# WPF - Bind command declaratively to code behind when different from the datacontext

Tags: xaml

I'm not so great with WPF, so I am looking at a WPF control that someone else has created which has a datacontext set to another class, but also has tons of code in the code-behind on the actual control.

I need to create a context menu command that binds to a method inside of the code behind, not the actual datacontext of the control. I know how to create the context menu, just looking for how to bind to code behind when using another datacontext on the control.

Thanks!

Comment: You can set the DataContext at the instance like <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding blah}"/>

Comment: Thanks! I know this, I am trying to find out what "blah" should equal lol. I did try this on my command: Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DeletePageCommand}"> where UserControl is the actual name of the user control. That got me intellisense and it picked up the method and everything, but it never actually fired.

Comment: Ah ok I'm not paying attention I'm sorry. ContextMenu doesn't live in the DOM the way you would expect. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662164/wpf-context-menu-doesnt-bind-to-right-databound-item) in which case if it's correct you might mark this as duplicate. :)

Comment: This does not work: <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" IsEnabled="{Binding AllowDelete, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </ContextMenu>

Comment: And this does not work: <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dp:ImageEditor}}, Path=AllowDelete}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>

Comment: This actually works in that the getter on the property is being hit whenever I expect it to however it is not actually disabling the menu item. Argggggghhhh!  <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UserControl}">
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" IsEnabled="{Binding AllowDelete}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>