# WPF MenuItem: How to bind a SubMenuItem command to to its Parent MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I want to Bind the e.g. "Debug|Any CPU" MenuItem Command which has its own BuildConfiguration Context to the Project Context BuildProjectCommand.
How to do it correctly?

I already tried to accomplish this with FindAncestor but it won't work.
e.g. `Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.BuildCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}"`

See picture for more understanding:
[image]

Comment: Binding popup menus can get tricky because of the way they are "disconnected" from the visual tree, they don't inherit the `DataContext` in the way you would expect.  There are a few [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662164/wpf-context-menu-doesnt-bind-to-right-databound-item) you can use though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a quick prototype and binding below should work as you expect:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type commmon:BuildConfiguration}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="ConfigBlock">
        <Run Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" 
                          Command="{Binding DataContext.BuildCommand, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=2, 
                          AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}">
            </MouseBinding>
        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks! that AncestorLevel was the hack :P